# Почему после выполнения метода 4-й раз, число перестаёт округляться

Tags: c#, .net

```
using System;

namespace Prakt1Spec
{

    class Elf
    {
        private string ElfName = "Jordan";
        private int ElfPower = 10;
        private int ElfAgility = 20;
        private double ElfBrain = 30;
        private int ElfStamina = 15;
        private int ElfLevel = 1;
        private int ElfPointOfLevel = 0;

        public void LearnMinusPower()
        {
            ElfPower -= 2;
        }
        
        private void CheckLevelPoint()
        {
            if (ElfPointOfLevel >= 100)
            {
                ElfLevel += 1;
                ElfPointOfLevel = ElfPointOfLevel - 100;
            }
        }

        public void ElfLearn()
        {
            ElfPower += 1;
            ElfAgility += 1;
            ElfBrain += Math.Round(ElfBrain*0.05, 1);
            ElfStamina += 1;
            ElfPointOfLevel += 30;

            CheckLevelPoint();
        }

        public void GetElfValue()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Имя Эльфа: {ElfName}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Уровень Эльфа: {ElfLevel}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Сила Эльфа: {ElfPower}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Ловкость Эльфа: {ElfAgility}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Интеллект Эльфа: {ElfBrain}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Выносливость Эльфа: {ElfStamina}");
            Console.WriteLine($"До следующего уровня осталось " +
                $"{100 - ElfPointOfLevel} очков");
        }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var Elf = new Elf();

            Elf.GetElfValue();
            Elf.ElfLearn();
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Elf.GetElfValue();
            Elf.ElfLearn();
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Elf.GetElfValue();
            Elf.ElfLearn();
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Elf.GetElfValue();
            Elf.ElfLearn();
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Elf.GetElfValue();
            Elf.ElfLearn();

        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А какая версия .NET, в какой ОС? У меня нормально вывелось.

Comment: У меня стоит Windows 10

Comment: Версия .NET 5.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это связано с тем, что десятичные дроби достаточно часто в двоичном виде представляются бесконечными периодическими дробями.

Здесь число округляется как надо

```
ElfBrain += Math.Round(ElfBrain*0.05, 1);
```

Но оно записывается в память, и то, что оказывается в памяти, не соотвествует в точности результату округления. А потом число берётся из памяти для вывода на экран.

В общем, нужно применить формат вывода

```
Console.WriteLine($"Интеллект Эльфа: {ElfBrain:F1}");
```

Comment: У меня просто F1 выводиться

Comment: Мне нужно чтоб числа выводились, я уже задумываюсь, чтоб просто до целого числа округляло

Comment: Строго говоря, число 34,8 не может быть точно представлено в компьютере  в формате чисел с плавающей точкой (стандарт IEEE 754) ни в памяти, ни в процессоре

Comment: так попробуйте Console.WriteLine("Интеллект Эльфа: {0:F1}", ElfBrain)

Comment: Получается никакого выхода нет?

Comment: Получилось, спасибо большое тебе ;)